# Typescript/Javascript - Parse float with comma as decimal separator

Tags: javascript, typescript, parsing, parsefloat

I have the following string:

```
const NumberAsString = "75,65";
```

And I need to parse it as float like this:

```
Amount: parseFloat(NumberAsString);
```

I've seen some post that suggested to replace the `comma` with a `dot` which works well when the `comma` is used as thousand separator. But in this case the `comma` is used as decimal separator If I replace it I get this number: `7.565,00` which is not my number `75.65`. Is there any way to parse this number to float without changing it's value?

PD: In my system I have a helper that takes the numbers with the dot as thousand separator and the comma as decimal separator. I cannot avoid this.

Comment: I don't follow where the `7.565,00` number came from in the question.

Comment: As I said if I do that the number will change, In my system the dot is used for thousands and the comma for decimals

Comment: Is `.` used as a thousands separator? How do you get `7.565,00`?

Comment: I will edit the post, In my system I have a function helper to convert the . as thousand separator and the comma as decimals separator and I cannot avoid that conversion

Answer (score -1):

Here is a clunky way of doing it. 
Using an array and `reduce`

```js
const tests = ['70,65', '7,000,01', '700'];

const parseNumber = (num) => {
  if(num === undefined) return undefined;
  if(num.indexOf(',') < 0) return parseFloat(num);
  const numArr = num.split(',');
  return parseFloat( numArr.reduce((a, v, i) => a + ((i === numArr.length - 1) ? `.${v}` : v), '') ); 
};

tests.forEach(t => console.log(parseNumber(t)));
```

Comment: it failed in some test cases:
// Test cases
const toFloat = "1.234.567,90";
const toFloat2 = "1,234,567.90";
const toFloat3 = "1234567,90";
const toFloat4 = "1234567.90";
const toFloat5 = "1234567.9";
const toFloat6 = "1234567";